# background image not showing

Tags: html, css

I have got this html:

```
<p class="separator" style="background:url('http://localhost:85/WebCamClone/public/images/home/separator.png') repeat-y;"></p>
```

and this css:

```
    p.separator {
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
width: 10px;
top: 0px;
right: 46px;
z-index: 999;
}
```

I can see the image when I open it in a new tab, but I cant see the image displayed on the page in p tag..why?

Comment: Of the situation so we can look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your `height: 100%;` your height can't stretch out as you would expect. to fix this problem you could try following options:

1. Give to your height pixel value like with your width
2. make your `html, body { height: 100%; }` and your `height: 100%;` will work either
3. assign `position: absolute` to your image

You could pick one of them each one should work.

Comment: your image will be served from localhost, could there be something with your port?

Comment: Okay, nvm, I swaped the p element for an image and it worked.. although that is not what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

maybe the absolute position cause this problem

To be sure use a color background , relative position as second step if first not working,third :use 'position : relative' to the parent container